# How to add/subtract an offset to/from NonNull<Opaque>?

Tags: rust

I provide two functions for managing memory:

```
unsafe extern "system" fn alloc<A: Alloc>(
    size: usize,
    alignment: usize,
) -> *mut c_void { ... }

unsafe extern "system" fn free<A: Alloc>(
    memory: *mut c_void
) { ... }
```

Both functions internally use the [allocator-api](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32838).

These signatures cannot be changed. The problem is that `free` does not ask for `size` and `alignment`, which is required for `Alloc::dealloc`. To get around this, `alloc` allocates some extra space for one [`Layout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/alloc/struct.Layout.html). `free` can now access this `Layout` to get the needed extra data.

Recently, the [allocator-api](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32838) changed and instead of `*mut u8` it now uses `NonNull<Opaque>`. This is where my problem occurs.

[`core::alloc::Opaque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/alloc/foreigntype.Opaque.html):

> An opaque, unsized type. Used for pointers to allocated memory. [...] Such pointers are similar to C’s `void*` type.

`Opaque` is not `Sized`, so the use of `NonNull::as_ptr().add()` and `NonNull::as_ptr().sub()` are forbidden.

Previously, I used something like this (for simplicity, I assume `Alloc`'s functions to be static):

```
#![feature(allocator_api)]
#![no_std]

extern crate libc;

use core::alloc::{Alloc, Layout};
use libc::c_void;

unsafe extern "system" fn alloc<A: Alloc>(
    size: usize,
    alignment: usize,
) -> *mut c_void
{
    let requested_layout =
        Layout::from_size_align(size, alignment).unwrap();

    let (layout, padding) = Layout::new::<Layout>()
        .extend_packed(requested_layout)
        .unwrap();

    let ptr = A::alloc(layout).unwrap(); 
    (ptr as *mut Layout).write(layout);
    ptr.add(padding)
}
```

The last line is not possible anymore with `NonNull<Opaque>`. How I can get around this?

Comment: What prevents you from casting the raw pointer to `*mut u8`?

Comment: @Shepmaster I wasn't sure, if this is UB or something.

Comment: @Tim As long as your allocate give mutable memory it's should be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably write it like this, using [`NonNull::as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/ptr/struct.NonNull.html#method.as_ptr) to get a `*mut Opaque` and then cast that to different concrete types:

```
#![feature(allocator_api)]
#![no_std]

extern crate libc;

use core::alloc::{Alloc, Layout};
use libc::c_void;

unsafe fn alloc<A: Alloc>(allocator: &mut A, size: usize, alignment: usize) -> *mut c_void {
    let requested_layout = Layout::from_size_align(size, alignment).expect("Invalid layout");

    let (layout, _padding) = Layout::new::<Layout>()
        .extend_packed(requested_layout)
        .expect("Unable to create layout");

    let ptr = allocator.alloc(layout).expect("Unable to allocate");

    // Get a pointer to our layout storage 
    let raw = ptr.as_ptr() as *mut Layout;
    // Save it
    raw.write(layout);
    // Skip over it
    raw.offset(1) as *mut _
}
```

---

> `unsafe extern "system" fn alloc<A: Alloc>(`

This makes no sense to me. The various FFI ABIs ("C", "system", etc.) have no way of specifying Rust generic types. It seems deeply incorrect for this function to be marked `extern`.

---

> `Layout::new::<Layout>().extend_packed(requested_layout)`

This seems likely to be very broken. As the [documentation for `Layout::extend_packed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/alloc/struct.Layout.html#method.extend_packed) states, emphasis mine:

> the alignment of `next` is irrelevant, and is **not incorporated at all into the resulting layout**.

Your returned pointer doesn't seem to honor the alignment request.

Comment: The generic in `alloc` is just for interpreting an opaque userdata-pointer. Regarding the `extend_packed`: Thanks for the hint, I'm using `extend` anyway, can't say, why I typed `extend_packed`, maybe because of autocompletition in my IDE...